# How to prevent this regex code from removing the period?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a code to turn dumb quotes to smart quotes:

```
text.replace(/\b"|\."/g, '&rdquo;')
```

(I added OR period because sometimes sentences end with a period not a word.)

Input:

```
"This is a text."
```

Output:

```
“This is a text”
```

Desired output:

```
“This is a text.”
```

As you can see, that code removes the dot.

How to prevent this?

RULES: I want to replace dumb double quotes that are at end of a word or after a period, turn them into right double smart quotes.

Comment: The replace method replaces the matched text with your replace text. If you don't want it replaced, don't match it.

Comment: I tested your `text.replace(/\b"|\."/g, '&rdquo;')` it didn't replaced and removed anything from `This is a text.`

Comment: you might want to learn what your regex does. here's a good place -> https://regexr.com/

Comment: here are some more resources: 
https://regex101.com/ -JS
http://regexstorm.net/tester -.Net

Comment: Try `.replace(/\B(")|\.(")/g, ($0,$1,$2) => $1 ? '&ldquo;' : '.&rdquo;')`. However, I am not quite sure what rules you are trying to follow with your pattern, please add them to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added the rules.

Comment: Then try https://stackoverflow.com/a/52294258/3832970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include in the replacement the capturing group 1 , you can do that with :

```
replace(/\b"$|(\.)"$/g, "$1&rdquo;");
```

$1 Will contain the .

Adding the $ you will avoid miss those cases:

```
"This is a "text"."
```

EDIT For the new RULE:

If you want also to replace the internal quotes of a quote do this >

```js
const regex = /( ")([\w\s.]*)"(?=.*"$)|\b"$|(\.)?"$/g;
const str = `"This is a "subquote" about "life"."`;
const subst = `$1$2$3&rdquo;`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

> "You live "your live" always in company"
>
> "You live "alone" always in company"
>
> "You live "" always in company"
>
> "You live "in the dark..." always in company"
>
> "You live "alone" very "alone" always in company"

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I commited a mistake, I fixed it.
 Thanks.

Comment: No, now you made another mistake. I only used `$0` in the demo because regex101 does not support `$&`. The problem is that your `$&` inserts `"` back. That is the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth, I will fix it

Comment: Finally replace(/\b"$|(\.)"$/g, "$1&rdquo;"); also to avoid  "This is a "text"."

Comment: This still not what OP needs, but it is not that bad any longer.

Comment: [It is awful](https://regex101.com/r/aHjKi4/1) as it causes catastrophic backtracking with a very short string.

Comment: true, I was using another software to test this regex, I have to fix it

Comment: No, the problem is still there: you can't have patterns like `(a*)+` (you have `([\w\s.]*)+`) in the middle of the pattern.

Comment: But I think you should not have patters like that, ok. In this case, can you put me an example of this pattern failing ? (Ej: CB)

Comment: It's my mistake, but it works removing the plus :
( ")([\w\s.]*)"(?=.*"$)|\b"$|(\.)?"$

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```js
let text = '"This is a text."'
console.log(
text.replace(/\b"|(\.)"/g,'$1\u201d')
)
```

Comment: Try with `let text = '"This is a "text"."'`, you will see `.` adding up where it should not be.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew: I've putted the dot in a group & I'm using it as a back reference